# How pass the file path to remote Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, file, tomcat, netbeans

I have a question.

I have a remote Web Service (Tomcat 7, Netbeans) that accepts in input a file (Excel, XML) from my client. Now, I want to read this file and I want to extract the information of the file in Java Code.
How can I pass the path of the file to my Web Service? I have to make some kind of serialization?

Comment: You pass the content not the path which is meaningless outside the host machine ...

Comment: Ok, how I pass the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice article on uploading files using REST API's - http://www.javatutorialscorner.com/2013/12/file-upload-using-jax-rs-restful.html

And this is a simple example using a servlet - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Ok. But, I have to convert String to ByteArrayOutputStream and then, ByteArrayOutputStream to String. How I can do it?

Comment: Dosnt http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm show you everything that you need with the file upload scenario? Why do you need to do this additionally? if its a different question can you create a new post?